# is there any way to assign a particular line to a variable which is frequently used?

Tags: javascript, dom

There is a frequent use of document.getElementById() in my code . so is there any way to abbreviate this long line of code to a small variable , if possible?

Comment: `var element = document.getElementById("someId");` and use `element` in other places

Comment: I tried the same earlier but it didn't happened the way i wanted. But thamkyou for the help

Comment: You can consider using `var ge=document.getElementById; ge("id");` but ideally this is a role of your bundling / minification framework. You should write code for understanding and let tools transform it during shipping of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper function like :

```
const byId = (id) => document.getElementById(id);
```

Or

Assign `document.getElementById`  to a variable by binding it with `document` object.

```
const byId = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

---

*Note: In second approach, If you don't bind `document.getElementById` with `document` you'll get error :*

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

What `Function.bind` does is it creates a new function with its `this` keyword set to value that you provide as argument to `Function.bind`.

Read docs for [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)